# No Metrics displayed in Application Insights for a Application deployed to a Virtual app

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

We are attempting to use MS Application Insights in a Web API deployed to a virtual application in an Azure App Service.  Currently this app service is deployed using Deployment Slots.

The following conditions are true:

1. ApplicationsInsights.config is being successfully deployed as verified by opening the app's console in the Azure Portal.
2. A second app deployed to a separate app service and with separate instrumentation key (otherwise configuration is identical) works perfectly.

The only differences other than instrumentation key are as follows:
 1. The API is deployed as a virtual application (defined in ApplicationSettings: Virtual Applications and directories) as app /1.0 to directory site\api10
 2. The app service is hosted in a deployment slot called UAT.

I am suspicious the issue occurs because (a) it is a virtual app or (b) is deployed to a deployment slot.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say WebAPI, is this using OWIN?

Comment: Yes.  Latest 5.2.3 Web api

Comment: Have you tried the OwinExtensions? https://github.com/marcinbudny/applicationinsights-owinextensions

Comment: Looks interesting, but I do not think this would help in this situation...It works fine on local machine, just not in azure :(

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I created my development slot and configure the "Virtual applications and directories" in "SETTINGS > Application settings" of my Web App on Azure Portal as follows:

Site URL: http://bruce-chen-001-staging01.azurewebsites.net/

[image]

Then I followed this [tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Instrumenting-your-Web-API-using-Application-Insights-with-Victor-Mushkatin) about instrumenting the Web API using Application Insights. After created the project, I deployed my app to a deployment slot of my Azure Web App.

[image]

Also, I checked my web content has been deployed to Azure successfully via KUDU.

[image]

Browser the following link and wait for a moment, then I could get my metrics as follows:

http://bruce-chen-001-staging01.azurewebsites.net/staging01/api/values

[image]

In summary, please try to check your steps and find whether you are missing something.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will get back with you as soon as I can test this.

Comment: Everything we see right now appears to be correct.  We use VSTS Release management to deploy but everything looks good as far as configuration.

Comment: Has this issue been solved?  I assumed that there be delay for metrics to display. If my reply could help you, you could mark it as an answer. Or if you modify some configuration, you could update your question or post an answer for other communities who could encounter the similar issue.

Comment: I was never able to get this to work.  We ended up not using AI at this point.  I think there is some sort of conflict amongst web.config and/or the AI config files but were not able to resolve this.

Comment: You could install/uninstall AI at Run time without rebuilding and redeploying your code. For more details, you could refer to [Monitor a live Azure web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now#monitor-a-live-azure-web-app).

Comment: Also, you could leverage New Relic, for more details you could refer to [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-portal).